# Extension of a gradient field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose that $V$ is a (sufficiently smooth) gradient field ($V$ is gradient of some function $f$) defined on a convex set. I was wondering under what conditions it can be extended to a gradient field in the whole space. It would be great if I could be referred to some papers or book chapters. Thank you.

Comment: Does "$V$ is a gradient field" mean $V = \nabla f$ for some function $f$? Do you just want to extend $V$ to some vector field, or do you want the gradient of an extension of $f$?

Comment: Yes, I mean V is the gradient of some function f and I would like to extend it to a gradient field in the whole space. Thank you for the questions and I edited the problem description.